# GridView columns with different sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I'm trying to make a gridview like below image. [image]

Is there any library? Could you please help me. Thanks Advance.

Answer (score 2):

`RecyclerView` with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` is what you are looking for.

[StaggeredGridLayoutManager example tutorial](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)

[StaggeredGridLayoutManager documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html)